# Can this PyGame code run 60fps for >40 critters?

Tags: optimization, pygame

[In my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614091/will-converting-to-pysdl2-make-my-app-run-faster-than-it-does-under-pygame?noredirect=1#comment74284041_43614091), some of the posters asked to see the code and suggested I make a new question. As requested, here is most of the code I'm using. I've removed the Vector class, simply because it's a lot of code. It's well-understood math that I got from someone else (https://gist.github.com/mcleonard/5351452), and cProfile didn't have much to say about any of the functions there. I've provided a link in the code, if you want to make this run-able.

This code should run, if you paste the the vector class where indicated in the code.

The problem is, once I get above 20 critters, the framerate drops rapidly from 60fps to 11fps around 50 critters.

Please excuse the spaghetti-code. Much of this is diagnostic kludging or pre-code that I intend to either remove, or turn into a behavior (instead of a hard-coded value).

This app is basically composed of 4 objects.

A Vector object provides abstracted vector operations.

A Heat Block is able to track it's own "heat" level, increase it and decrease it. It can also draw itself.

A Heat Map is composed of heat blocks which are tiled across the screen. When given coordinates, it can choose the block that those coordinates fall within.

A Critter has many features that make it able to wander around the screen, bump off of the walls and other critters, choose a new random direction, and die.

The main loop iterates through each critter in the "flock" and updates its "condition" (whether or not it's "dying"), its location, its orientation, and the heat block on which it is currently standing. The loop also iterates over each heat block to let it "cool down."

Then the main loop asks the heat map to draw itself, and then each critter in the flock to draw itself.

```
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw
import pygame.locals
import os
import math
import random
import time

(I got a nice vector class from someone else. It's large, and mostly likely not the problem.)
(INSERT CONTENTS OF VECTOR.PY FROM https://gist.github.com/mcleonard/5351452 HERE)


pygame.init()

#some global constants
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
diagnostic = False
SPAWN_TIME = 1 #number of seconds between creating new critters
FLOCK_LIMIT = 30 #number of critters at which the flock begins being culled
GUIDs = [0] #list of guaranteed unique IDs for identifying each critter

# Set the position of the OS window
position = (30, 30)
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = str(position[0]) + "," + str(position[1])

# Set the position, width and height of the screen [width, height]
size_x = 1000
size_y = 500
size = (size_x, size_y)
FRAMERATE = 60
SECS_FOR_DYING = 1
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
screen.set_alpha(None)
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def random_float(lower, upper):
    num = random.randint(lower*1000, upper*1000)
    return num/1000


def new_GUID():
    num = GUIDs[-1]
    num = num + 1
    while num in GUIDs:
        num += 1
    GUIDs.append(num)
    return num


class HeatBlock:
    def __init__(self,_tlx,_tly,h,w):
        self.tlx = int(_tlx)
        self.tly = int(_tly)
        self.height = int(h)+1
        self.width = int(w)
        self.heat = 255.0
        self.registered = False

    def register_tresspasser(self):
        self.registered = True
        self.heat = max(self.heat - 1, 0)

    def cool_down(self):
        if not self.registered:
            self.heat = min(self.heat + 0.1, 255)
        self.registered = False

    def hb_draw_self(self):
        screen.fill((255,int(self.heat),int(self.heat)), [self.tlx, self.tly, self.width, self.height])


class HeatMap:
    def __init__(self, _h, _v):
        self.h_freq = _h #horizontal frequency
        self.h_rez = size_x/self.h_freq #horizontal resolution
        self.v_freq = _v #vertical frequency
        self.v_rez = size_y/self.v_freq #vertical resolution
        self.blocks = [] 

    def make_map(self):
        h_size = size_x/self.h_freq
        v_size = size_y/self.v_freq
        for h_count in range(0, self.h_freq):
            TLx = h_count * h_size #TopLeft corner, x
            col = []
            for v_count in range(0, self.v_freq):
                TLy = v_count * v_size #TopLeft corner, y
                col.append(HeatBlock(TLx,TLy,v_size,h_size))
            self.blocks.append(col)

    def hm_draw_self(self):
        for col in self.blocks:
            for block in col:
                block.cool_down()
                block.hb_draw_self()

    def register(self, x, y):
        #convert the given coordinates of the trespasser into a col/row block index
        col = max(int(math.floor(x / self.h_rez)),0)
        row = max(int(math.floor(y / self.v_rez)),0)
        self.blocks[col][row].register_tresspasser()


class Critter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = (random.randint(1, 200), random.randint(1, 200), random.randint(1, 200))
        self.linear_speed = random_float(20, 100)
        self.radius = int(round(10 * (100/self.linear_speed)))
        self.angular_speed = random_float(0.1, 2)
        self.x = int(random.randint(self.radius*2, size_x - (self.radius*2)))
        self.y = int(random.randint(self.radius*2, size_y - (self.radius*2)))
        self.orientation = Vector(0, 1).rotate(random.randint(-180, 180))
        self.sensor = Vector(0, 20)
        self.sensor_length = 20
        self.new_orientation = self.orientation
        self.draw_bounds = False
        self.GUID = new_GUID()
        self.condition = 0 #0 = alive, [1-fps] = dying, >fps = dead
        self.delete_me = False

    def c_draw_self(self):
        #if we're alive and not dying, draw our normal self
        if self.condition == 0:
            #diagnostic
            if self.draw_bounds:
                pygame.gfxdraw.rectangle(screen, [int(self.x), int(self.y), 1, 1], BLUE)
                temp = self.orientation * (self.linear_speed * 20)
                pygame.gfxdraw.line(screen, int(self.x), int(self.y), int(self.x + temp[0]), int(self.y + temp[1]), BLUE)
            #if there's a new orientation, match it gradually
            temp = self.new_orientation * self.linear_speed
            #draw my body
            pygame.gfxdraw.aacircle(screen, int(self.x), int(self.y), self.radius, self.color)
            #draw a line indicating my new direction
            pygame.gfxdraw.line(screen, int(self.x), int(self.y), int(self.x + temp[0]), int(self.y + temp[1]), BLUE)
            #draw my sensor (a line pointing forward)
            self.sensor = self.orientation.normalize() * self.sensor_length
            pygame.gfxdraw.line(screen, int(self.x), int(self.y), int(self.x + self.sensor[0]), int(self.y + self.sensor[1]), BLUE)
        #otherwise we're dying, draw our dying animation
        elif 1 <= self.condition <= FRAMERATE*SECS_FOR_DYING:
            #draw some lines in a spinningi circle
            for num in range(0,10):
                line = Vector(0, 1).rotate((num*(360/10))+(self.condition*23))
                line = line*self.radius
                pygame.gfxdraw.line(screen, int(self.x), int(self.y), int(self.x+line[0]), int(self.y+line[1]), self.color)

    def print_self(self):
        #diagnostic
        print("==============")
        print("radius:", self.radius)
        print("color:", self.color)
        print("linear_speed:", self.linear_speed)
        print("angular_speed:", self.angular_speed)
        print("x:", self.x)
        print("y:", int(self.y))
        print("orientation:", self.orientation)

    def avoid_others(self, _flock):
        for _critter in _flock:
            #if the critter isn't ME...
            if _critter.GUID is not self.GUID and _critter.condition == 0:
                #and it's touching me...
                if self.x - _critter.x <= self.radius + _critter.radius:
                    me = Vector(self.x, int(self.y))
                    other_guy = Vector(_critter.x, _critter.y)
                    distance = me - other_guy

                    #give me new orientation that's away from the other guy
                    if distance.norm() <= ((self.radius) + (_critter.radius)):
                        new_direction = me - other_guy
                        self.orientation = self.new_orientation = new_direction.normalize()

    def update_location(self, elapsed):
        boundary = '?'
        while boundary != 'X':
            boundary = self.out_of_bounds()
            if boundary == 'N':
                self.orientation = self.new_orientation = Vector(0, 1).rotate(random.randint(-20, 20))
                self.y = (self.radius) + 2
            elif boundary == 'S':
                self.orientation = self.new_orientation = Vector(0,-1).rotate(random.randint(-20, 20))
                self.y = (size_y - (self.radius)) - 2
            elif boundary == 'E':
                self.orientation = self.new_orientation = Vector(-1,0).rotate(random.randint(-20, 20))
                self.x = (size_x - (self.radius)) - 2
            elif boundary == 'W':
                self.orientation = self.new_orientation = Vector(1,0).rotate(random.randint(-20, 20))
                self.x = (self.radius) + 2
            point = Vector(self.x, self.y)
            self.x, self.y = (point + (self.orientation * (self.linear_speed*(elapsed/1000))))
            boundary = self.out_of_bounds()

    def update_orientation(self, elapsed):
        #randomly choose a new direction, from time to time
        if random.randint(0, 100) > 98:
            self.choose_new_orientation()
        difference = self.orientation.argument() - self.new_orientation.argument()
        self.orientation = self.orientation.rotate((difference * (self.angular_speed*(elapsed/1000))))

    def still_alive(self, elapsed):
        return_value = True #I am still alive
        if self.condition == 0:
            return_value = True
        elif self.condition <= FRAMERATE*SECS_FOR_DYING:
            self.condition = self.condition + (elapsed/17)
            return_value = True
        if self.condition > FRAMERATE*SECS_FOR_DYING:
            return_value = False

        return return_value

    def choose_new_orientation(self):
        if self.new_orientation:
            if (self.orientation.argument() - self.new_orientation.argument()) < 5:
                rotation = random.randint(-300, 300)
                self.new_orientation = self.orientation.rotate(rotation)

    def out_of_bounds(self):
        if self.x >= (size_x - (self.radius)):
            return 'E'
        elif self.y >= (size_y - (self.radius)):
            return 'S'
        elif self.x <= (0 + (self.radius)):
            return 'W'
        elif self.y <= (0 + (self.radius)):
            return 'N'
        else:
            return 'X'


# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
# generate critters
flock = [Critter()]
# generate heat map
heatMap = HeatMap(60, 40)
heatMap.make_map()
# set some settings
last_spawn = time.clock()
run_time = time.perf_counter()
frame_count = 0
max_time = 0
ms_elapsed = 1
avg_fps = [1]
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop only processes one event
    frame_count = frame_count + 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here
    #check if it's time to make another critter
    if time.clock() - last_spawn > SPAWN_TIME:
        flock.append(Critter())
        last_spawn = time.clock()
    if len(flock) >= FLOCK_LIMIT:
        #if we're over the flock limit, cull the herd
        counter = FLOCK_LIMIT
        for critter in flock[0:len(flock)-FLOCK_LIMIT]:
            #this code allows a critter to be "dying" for a while, to play an animation
            if critter.condition == 0:
                critter.condition = 1
            elif not critter.still_alive(ms_elapsed):
                critter.delete_me = True
    counter = 0

    #delete all the critters that have finished dying
    while counter < len(flock):
        if flock[counter].delete_me:
            del flock[counter]
        else:
            counter = counter+1

    #----loop on all critters once, doing all functions for each critter
    for critter in flock:
        if critter.condition == 0:
            critter.avoid_others(flock)
            if critter.condition == 0:
                heatMap.register(critter.x, critter.y)
            critter.update_location(ms_elapsed)
            critter.update_orientation(ms_elapsed)
            if diagnostic:
                critter.print_self()

    #----alternately, loop for each function. Speed seems to be similar either way
    #for critter in flock:
    #    if critter.condition == 0:
    #        critter.update_location(ms_elapsed)
    #for critter in flock:
    #    if critter.condition == 0:
    #        critter.update_orientation(ms_elapsed)

    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

    # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # --- Drawing code should go here
    #draw the heat_map
    heatMap.hm_draw_self()
    for critter in flock:
        critter.c_draw_self()

    #draw the framerate
    myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
    #average the framerate over 60 frames
    temp = sum(avg_fps)/float(len(avg_fps)) 
    text = str(round(((1/temp)*1000),0))+"FPS | "+str(len(flock))+" Critters"
    label = myfont.render(text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(label, (5, 5))

    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.update()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    #only run for 30 seconds
    if time.perf_counter()-run_time >= 30:
        done = True
    #limit to 60fps
    #add this frame's time to the list
    avg_fps.append(ms_elapsed)
    #remove any old frames
    while len(avg_fps) > 60:
        del avg_fps[0]
    ms_elapsed = clock.tick(FRAMERATE)
    #track longest frame
    if ms_elapsed > max_time:
        max_time = ms_elapsed

#print some stats once the program is finished
print("Count:", frame_count)
print("Max time since last flip:", str(max_time)+"ms")
print("Total Time:", str(int(time.perf_counter()-run_time))+"s")
print("Average time for a flip:", str(int(((time.perf_counter()-run_time)/frame_count)*1000))+"ms")
# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can already do to improve the performance is to use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) instead of your `Vector` class, because it's implemented in C and therefore faster. Before I switched to pygame's vector class, I could have ~50 critters on the screen before the frame rate dropped below 60, and after the change up to ~100.

`pygame.math.Vector2` doesn't have that `argument` method, so you need to extract it from the class and turn it into a function:

```
def argument(vec):
    """ Returns the argument of the vector, the angle clockwise from +y."""
    arg_in_rad = math.acos(Vector(0,1)*vec/vec.length())
    arg_in_deg = math.degrees(arg_in_rad)
    if vec.x < 0:
        return 360 - arg_in_deg
    else:
        return arg_in_deg
```

And change `.norm()` to `.length()` everywhere in the program.

---

Also, define the font object (`myfont`) before the while loop. That's only a minor improvement, but every frame counts.

Comment: I'll take another look at the program tomorrow. BTW, do you know Cython? Perhaps some critical parts of the code could be cythonized. A profile showed that the `avoid_others` method is pretty hot.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations! I noticed avoid_others as well. My hope was to find a way to check fewer critters, or check them in a more efficient order, but checking their distances is probably just as costly one way as the other. I don't know Cython, but I'll look into it. I'm beginning to suspect that I'm simply asking PyGame to do more than it can, and the only real gains are going to come from switching to PySDL2 or recoding in C++ altogether.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll gain much by switching to PySDL2, since the main problem is the slow Python code (`avoid_others`). The `fill`ing in the `hm_draw_self` + `hb_draw_self` methods is also pretty costly, but I don't know if PySDL2 can fill more quickly or if there's a completely different, faster way to do it. Cythonizing the code (it creates C extensions) would only be my last step to optimize the code. What's your actual goal? How many critters do you want to display at the same time?

Comment: Let me know if switching to PySDL2 helps. I only took a quick look at it a long time ago, but quit because there were not many learning resources and third party libs available.

Comment: BTW, questions about the performance should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the suggestions! I'm hoping to be able to simulate up to 1000 of these things, eventually, and give them much more sophisticated behavior. Consequently, I think anything less than a serious overhaul is going to yield only marginal benefit.

Comment: I doubt that will work with standard Python code + pygame, but maybe if you make heavy use of Cython, numpy and what else you can find to improve the performance. I'd probably switch to PySDL2 or pyglet as well. Personally I'm currently using Pymunk (the physics library) in conjunction with pygame to make a racing game and can have around 2000 bodies on the screen with 30 fps, but I don't know how your critter interaction code would affect the performance. If my tips were helpful, you can give me an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Another change that made a significant improvement was to streamline my collision-detection algorithm.

Formerly, I had been looping through every critter in the flock, and measuring the distance between it and every other critter in the flock. If that distance was small enough, I do something. That's n^2 checks, which is not awesome.

I'd thought about using a quadtree, but it didn't seem efficient to rebalance the whole tree every frame, because it will change every time a critter moves.

Well, I finally actually tried it, and it turns out that building a brand-new quadtree at the beginning of each frame is actually plenty fast. Once I have the tree, I pass it to the avoidance function where I just extract an intersection of any of the critters in that tree within a bounding box I care about. Then I just iterate on those neighbors to measure distances and update directions and whatnot.

Now I'm up to 150 or so critters before I start dropping frames (up from 40).

So the moral of the story is, trust evidence instead of intuition.